# Join tables with non-equal rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use the relatively new data type in Matlab, `table`. I have a number of variables that each contains a value for a set of parameters (`Rows`). The rows are not (necessarily) equal for each variable, however. I want to join the variables together so the results are all displayed in a single table. E.g., I want to join these together: (drawn side by side to save space)

```
          Var_A                    Var_B 
         ________                 _______
    a     0.36744            b    0.88517
    b     0.98798            c    0.91329
    c    0.037739            d    0.79618
```

Is it possible to join these two tables?
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
A = table(rand(3,1),'VariableNames',{'Var_A'},'RowNames',{'a','b','c'})
B = table(rand(3,1),'VariableNames',{'Var_B'},'RowNames',{'b','c','d'})

try
  C = join(A,B)
catch e
  disp(e.identifier)
  disp(e.message)
end
```

This results in:

```
MATLAB:table:join:CantInferKey
Cannot find a common table variable to use as a key variable.
```

Okay, so maybe `join` isn't intended for this -- what about `outerjoin`? Its documentation sounds promising:

> *The outer join includes the rows that match between A and B, and also unmatched rows from either A or B, all with respect to the key variables. C contains all variables from both A and B, including the key variables.*

Well, `outerjoin` apparently can't be used with tables with row names! This is the closest I've found that does what I want, but seems to be against the idea of the `table` data structure to some degree:

```
AA = table({'a';'b';'c'},rand(3,1));
AA.Properties.VariableNames = {'param','Var_A'}

BB = table({'b';'c';'d'},rand(3,1));
BB.Properties.VariableNames = {'param','Var_B'}

CC = outerjoin(AA,BB,'Keys',1,'MergeKeys',true)
```

This results in

```
param     Var_A      Var_B 
_____    _______    _______

'a'      0.10676        NaN
'b'      0.65376    0.77905
'c'      0.49417    0.71504
'd'          NaN    0.90372
```

I.e., the `row` is just stored as a separate variable. This means it can't be indexed using "logical" notation such as `CC{'a',:}`.

So this can be fixed with:

```
CCC = CC(:,2:end);
CCC.Properties.RowNames = CC{:,1}
```

Which finally results in:

```
CCC = 

          Var_A      Var_B  
         _______    ________

    a     0.4168         NaN
    b    0.65686     0.29198
    c    0.62797     0.43165
    d        NaN    0.015487
```

But is this really the best way to go about things? Matlab is weird.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way to do this, but here is another option:

```
clear;

%// Create two tables to play with.
tableA = table([.5;  .6;  .7 ],'variablenames',{'varA'},'rowname',{'a','b','c'});
tableB = table([.55; .62; .68],'variablenames',{'varB'},'rowname',{'b','c','d'});

%// Lets add rows to tableA so that it has the same rows as tableB
%// First, get the set difference of tableB rows and tableA rows
%// Then, make a new table with those rows and NaN for data.
%// Finally, concatenate tableA with the new table
tableAnewRows=setdiff(tableB.Properties.RowNames,tableA.Properties.RowNames);
tableAadd=table( nan(length(tableAnewRows),1) ,'variablenames',{'varA'},'rownames',tableAnewRows);
tableA=[tableA;tableAadd];

%// Lets add rows to tableB so that it has the same rows as tableA
tableBnewRows=setdiff(tableA.Properties.RowNames,tableB.Properties.RowNames);
tableBadd=table( nan(length(tableBnewRows),1) ,'variablenames',{'varB'},'rownames',tableBnewRows);
tableB=[tableB;tableBadd];

%// Form tableC from tableA and tableB. Could also use join().
tableC=[tableA tableB];
```

Comment: "there must be a better way" is exactly what I was thinking the whole time I was trying to solve the problem the first time around!